# Read a json file in memory discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to get a jsonfile from a website into memory and then reading the contents of it. But I can't quite figure out how to do...
This is what I've done

```
@bot.command(name="meme")
async def memcommand(ctx, type: str = None):
    if type is None:
        subreddit = reddit.subreddit("memes")
        submission = subreddit.random()
        posturl = f"https://www.reddit.com/r/memes/comments/{submission}/.json"
        try:
            # urllib.request.urlretrieve(posturl, f'reddit_jsons/{submission}.json')
            r = requests.get(posturl)
            inmemoryfile = io.BytesIO(r.content)
        except Exception:
            await ctx.send(f"Seems like reddit doesn't like this many requests... Let's wait a bit....")
            return
        with open(inmemoryfile) as f: # This throws the error
            actualfile = json.load(f)
        imgurl = actualfile[0]['data']['children'][0]['data']['url']
```

The error is

```
Ignoring exception in command meme:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xlysa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:/Ficheiros/Pastas/Tudo/Coding/Python/Projects/Server-Utils/bot.py", line 958, in memcommand
    with open(inmemoryfile) as f:
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.BytesIO

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xlysa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\xlysa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xlysa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.BytesIO
```

If it can't be this way, how can I open the file and see its content?

Comment: Can you post the full error message. It's hard to determine which line is responsible.

Comment: `r = requests.get(posturl)` - is that the `requests` module? `r.json()` should decode the json into python for you.

Comment: The line that throws the error is specified but ok. I'll edit the question

Comment: @tdelaney it is.. Can I do that? Then how can I read it and get info from it?

Comment: `info = r.json()`. Now its just a python object. How you use it depends on the API - whatever is  defined to be returned by the call. Its likely either a list or a dict.

Comment: `open` function used to open real file by file name. You `inmemoryfile` already like file object and you can just use `json.load(inmemoryfile)`. You don't need to open anything

Comment: As a side note, `requests.get` is a blocking call and shouldn't  be made with `async` functions. I think that [grequests](https://github.com/spyoungtech/grequests) is the async version of requests.

Comment: @Stavinsky -  I thinlk you'd still have to worry about decoding the data. Using the response `.json()` method should figure that out for you.

Comment: @tdelaney r.content should return bytes object, I don't know why we putting this data to stream object, but it is different question. so BytesIO from bytes will give us stream object. that object has .read() method and this method will be colled in json.load()

You right better to use .json() without all this staff. Or json.loads(r.content) not better but still works

Comment: @Stavinsky the `requests.io.Response` object has a `json` method that takes care of both the string decoding (e.g., utf-8) and JSON decoding of the object. It honors any compression and byte encoding included in the http resposne header. One stop shopping. Not need for r.content and etc.

Comment: @tdelaney as I said you absolutly right. But Author asked why he sees that error and I just tryed to explain this error, why it happened and how to avoid it by changing only 2 lines. And for sure your answer is correct. )
About compression I was thinking .content already decompressed by requests. And decompression is on lower level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `requests.Response` object has a `json` method that will read the json for you. Note that with an `async` function you should not do a blocking `requests.get`. This answer focuses on the json part.

```
@bot.command(name="meme")
async def memcommand(ctx, type: str = None):
    if type is None:
        subreddit = reddit.subreddit("memes")
        submission = subreddit.random()
        posturl = f"https://www.reddit.com/r/memes/comments/{submission}/.json"
        try:
            # urllib.request.urlretrieve(posturl, f'reddit_jsons/{submission}.json')
            r = requests.get(posturl)
        except Exception:
            await ctx.send(f"Seems like reddit doesn't like this many requests... Let's wait a bit....")
            return
        actualfile = r.json()
        imgurl = actualfile[0]['data']['children'][0]['data']['url']
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to see if it works. If it does I accept this as the answer.

Comment: If it fails, `print(r.content)` and `print(r.headers)` so we can look at the reason. Sometimes the request needs information in its header to get the response right.

Comment: It was giving an error so I'me debugging and discovered that `r = requests.get(postrul)` is `<Response 429> which is too many requests... I'll assume I just have to wait to see if I can use it?

Comment: @Lysander12PT - Ouch! Yeah, I think so.

Comment: Almost one hour has passed and still the same problem... Maybe something is incorrect? http://prntscr.com/tzr2io

Comment: Searching "reddit.com 429" gave me hits suggesting that the default requests user-agent gets throttled by reddit. Adding `headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}` may help.

Comment: yep, that worked tyvm. Gonna mark this as the answer